# Changing some characters from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to change some characters from a string input. For example, if the sentence contains e, it will be printed as ᴇ, or t's as ᴛ. To be more specified, if user types in the string "test" it'll be printed back as "ᴛᴇsᴛ". But I am having a problem, here is my code:

```
'''
Qǫ Ww Eᴇ Rʀ Tᴛ Yʏ Uᴜ i Oᴏ Pᴘ
α Ŝ̬ Dᴅ Fғ Gɢ Hʜ Jj Kᴋ Lʟ
Zᴢ X Vᴠ β Nɴ Mᴍ 
'''


x = "qertyuIpaAsSdfghklxbBnm."
y = "ǫᴇʀᴛʏᴜiᴘααŜ̬Ŝ̬ᴅғɢʜᴋʟXββɴᴍ"
trans = str.maketrans(x, y)
text = input("Write your sentence: ")
print (text.translate(trans))
```

The error: the first two maketrans arguments must have equal length

Comment: What's the output of `print(len(x), len(y))`?

Comment: Well, not sure why but it's 24 and 26.

Comment: Since that you asked me to print the length, I thought it had to be that some characters should've taken more than one space. AS I was searching I found that the "Ŝ̬" actually contains two characters. You can observe it when you try to delete the letter in the editor. I've found the solution!

Comment: it's because `Ŝ̬` takes two places, one for `S` with top accent, and then another for the bottom accent. Try doing `len(Ŝ̬)`